# scrolling content between fixed header & footer with variable height

Tags: jquery, css

I have a header and a footer, that should be `position: fixed`,
both have content that varies their height according to the page width,
I need the content between them to be scroll-able and that the header & footer will not cover it.
here is an example (of the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/ilyaD/bNSZu/2/
Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNSZu/5/)

Use `max-height`,`min-height` and height as percentages.Along with `overflow-y:auto`

Comment: i think you didn't update the demo since i see my fiddle only

Comment: thanx but this doesn't solve the problem, i still have a the size of the header is not fluid

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `max-height` to `#main` div and add this style to `#main` to fire the scroll bar

```
#main {
   overflow-y:auto; 
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/bNSZu/4/)